# Is the text editor in vs10 is made with richtextbox?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2012

I am using Visual Studio 2010. Using what, the text editor of this IDE is built? More generally, in different programming/coding IDE, text editor's are made of what?

I can think of richtextbox's. But cannot think how? What they realy use for the text editor?

Comment: I would expect it's custom. And this is is sort of off topic really no?

Comment: Off topic? may be. but i feel to know and google was not so helpful this time.

Comment: I suspect the only people who can tell are the team that develop VS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C# and WPF was used to devolop the IDE of VS2010. No RichTextBox.